# JSP cannot find css files (java-based webconfig)

Tags: css, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to spring and I am having this issue in a Spring application (Java-based config).

My application cannot locate static resources (css files, js, e.t.c)
I have tried different things and this issues still persists.

I have the following in my WebAppConfig.java file is as follows:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.x.apimanager")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.x.apimanager.repository")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

// Other codes here that is not shown.
 @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

My directory structure looks like this (The picture can be seen at the link below):
http://pbrd.co/1EAR1II

My Spring Security Config file looks like this.I added an interceptor that will allow requests for the particular folder to pass.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //Implementation not shown
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }
}
```

This is what firebug displays when this issue happens on the jsp page/view.

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:9999/apimanager/resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css"
navbar.css
```

My jsp page contains the following:

```
<c:set var="url">${pageContext.request.requestURL}</c:set>
<base href="${fn:substring(url, 0, fn:length(url) - fn:length(pageContext.request.requestURI))}${pageContext.request.contextPath}/" />
<link href="resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

My logs show the following:

```
2015-01-22 12:07:39 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:97 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:171 - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@e18bbb85: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@e18bbb85: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@a5979349: Username: x; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@12afc: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 0102DF1734E5DCC343FF4C767FE3AD17; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER'
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter:129 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@528199b
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css at position 5 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:127 - Request 'GET /resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css at position 6 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:127 - Request 'GET /resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css' doesn't match 'POST /login
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css at position 7 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css at position 8 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css at position 9 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css at position 10 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css at position 11 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter:107 - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@e18bbb85: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@a5979349: Username: x; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@12afc: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 0102DF1734E5DCC343FF4C767FE3AD17; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER'
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css at position 12 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css at position 13 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css at position 14 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:194 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css; Attributes: [authenticated]
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:310 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@e18bbb85: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@a5979349: Username: x; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@12afc: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 0102DF1734E5DCC343FF4C767FE3AD17; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:65 - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@49950c0d, returned: 1
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:215 - Authorization successful
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:227 - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:323 - /resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:823 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/apimanager/resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css]
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:226 - Looking up handler method for path /resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:236 - Did not find handler method for [/resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css]
2015-01-22 12:07:40 WARN  PageNotFound:1108 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/apimanager/resources/libs/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/navbar.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:966 - Successfully completed request
2015-01-22 12:07:40 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:115 - Chain processed normally
```

I will appreciate a solution to this issue. Thank you very much for answering my questions.

Answer (score 0):

i hope what you are missing is the application context path.

try this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/navbar.css" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Ekansh. I had already tried that. That was the first option I tried when trying to access the resource through the href attribute. It did not work. By the way it still resolved to the same path that the jsp code snippet above resolved to.

Comment: have u made sure that your resources folder is under webapp folder

Comment: Yes the resources are under that folder. You can have a look at my directory structure (http://pbrd.co/1EAR1II). Thanks.

Comment: I have also used the format that you specified above and it still is not working.